# Regex unicode range[uXXXX] not identified with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

I am trying to remove control characters(eg:\u0005) present in ajax response string.
The regular expression I am using is : `msg = msg.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');`

The regular expression is working when I statically assign a string to a variable, but the same expression is not working in my ajax call.

```
// send command
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "/data/test.txt",
    dataType: 'text',
    data: tmpCommand
})
.done( function(msg){

    //remove C1 and C0 control characters from response string
    msg = msg.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, ''); //not working
    //msg = msg.replace(/[\u0000-\u0009]/g, ''); //not working
    //msg = msg.replace(/\\u0005/g, ""); //working


    response= $.parseJSON(msg);
    console.log(response);

})
.always(function(msg){

});
```

The response from below is in JSON string. For example: {"name1":"\u0005ABC","name2":"\u0005fgav"}

What could be the issue?

Comment: Just tried in the Chrome Console. Looks like your regex works:  var x = "x\u0005x";var y = x.replace(/[\u0000-\u0009]/g, "");var z = x.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');console.log(x.length + ' ' + y.length + ' ' + z.length);

Comment: @qianfg The regex is working like that, but it's not working with ajax response.

Comment: Can you set a break point at the replace line, and see if the length of msg changes before and after the replace?

Comment: There's no reason why it would work differently there. Are you sure the `msg` does actually have the content you expected?

Comment: @qianfg length is the same before and after replace in ajax

Comment: @Bergi yes msg has content in JSON string like : {"name1":"\u0005ABC","name2":"\u0005fgav"}

Comment: @coder123 Ah, now we're getting somewhere. I would've guessed this in the first place if you had not loaded a `.txt` file :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to remove control characters (eg:\u0005) present in ajax response string.
>   The response is a JSON string, for example
>
> ```
> {"name1":"\u0005ABC","name2":"\u0005fgav"}
> ```
>
> What could be the issue?

That there are no control characters in the response text. The response text is JSON which contains *escape sequences* for those control characters you're looking for. There is no single enquiry character, there's a backslash character followed by an `u` followed by digits. This is why `.replace(/\\u0005/g, "")` - which matches them one by one - works.

If you want to replace (and match with a character class range) the control characters themselves, you have to parse the JSON escape sequences first:

```
var data = JSON.parse(message);
data.name1 = data.name1.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');
data.name2 = data.name2.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');
```

In total, I'd recommend to use the [reviver callback of the native `JSON.parse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) for this:

```
$.ajax(…).then(function(msg) {
    return JSON.parse(msg, function(p, v) {
        return typeof v == "string"
          ? v.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '')
          : v;
    });
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    …
});
```

Comment: This works! 
But if I assign a variable say, `var msg ='{"name1":"\u0005ABC","name2":"\u0005fgav"}';` Then I don't need to parse JSON. Simply using `msg = msg.replace(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');` works. 
But this isn't the case with ajax response. Why is this so?

Comment: Because that's a string literal, in which `\u0005` represents the enquiry character. The ajax response in contrast is the plain response text, equivalent to the string that was constructed by a `'{"name1":"\\u0005ABC","name2":"\\u0005fgav"}'` literal (in which ``\\`` represents the backslash character).